# How to use remote and compare attributes in one method in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an MVC 5 application and using the built in **AccountController** methods for User Registrations. I have added a User Name property in **RegisterViewModel** since I needed that. Now I want to add Remote Validation on User Name property to prompt the user immediately if the user name is repeating.

But when I tried Remote Validation and added **System.Web.Mvc** reference, the **Compare** attribute for Password and Confirm Password started giving error.

I went through some study online and got that **System.Web.Mvc** has also got a Compare method and adding a reference to this class confused the compiler about Compare method.

My RegisterViewModel is:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed.")]
        [Remote("DuplicateUserName", "Account", ErrorMessage = "UserName already exists.")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

    }
```

The error it gave is:

> > **'CompareAttribute' is an ambiguous reference between
> >      'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute' and
> >      'System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute'**

Now I cannot delete the reference to using **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations** class because I am using Required and Display attributes of that class. But I also want to add Remote Validation. How can I do it?

Comment: Just add the namespace `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password" ...`

Comment: I am observing rather weird case.. My remote validations are not breaking in AccountController... But when I changed the Controller to some other.. It breaks just fine..

Comment: No idea what your saying :). (what do you mean by _breaking_?) You need to ask a new question with a better explanation and the relevant code

Comment: Sorry.. By breaking I mean..When I run the code in Debug mode and insert a break point at my validation method.. It simply won't break when thew method is in accountcontroller. But do break when I moved the method to some other controller

Comment: No psychics on SO :). You need to ask a new question with the relevant code.

Comment: I got it.. The problem was I have to [AllowAnonymous] the method because the AccountController has [Authorize] attribute on top. Thanks for your discussion and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the full namespace to the attrubute

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Alternatively you can add an alias to your usings

```
using Remote = System.Web.Mvc.RemoteAttribute;
```

Comment: I am observing rather weird case.. My remote validations are not breaking in AccountController... But when I changed the Controller to some other.. It breaks just fine..

Answer (score 2):

You can give the full path to the attribute, for instance:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```